# nth-child not working with CSS table-cell

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-tables

nth-child not working with css table-cell

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.table {
border: 1px solid black;
display: table;
height: 30px;
width: 200px;
}

.cell {
display: table-cell;
}

.table:nth-child(1) {
background-color: red;
width: 10%;
}

.table:nth-child(2) {
background-color: green;
width: 50%;
}

.table:nth-child(3) {
background-color: blue;
width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing your call from `.table:nth-child()` to `.cell:nth-child()`?  Seems to have the effect you want but I'm not a CSS expert so I can't say for sure if this a cardinal sin.

Comment: Cool. {.table .cell:nth-child()} It works. That strange logic.

Comment: You'll find CSS is a very fickle thing at times.  If you know someone who is really good with CSS run it by him/her to make sure I didn't give you a terrible solution.  I'm willing to bet there is some nesting stuff going on that makes the `nth-child` not work but I can't say for sure.

Comment: That was truly beginner misunderstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The nth-child selector does not operate from the parent's perspective
>   so can you please add below css and see results

```
 .table .cell:nth-child(1) {
                background-color: red;
                width: 10%;
                }

                .table .cell:nth-child(2) {
                background-color: green;
                width: 50%;
                }

                .table .cell:nth-child(3) {
                background-color: blue;
                width: 20%;
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct css:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.table {
border: 1px solid black;
display: table;
height: 30px;
width: 200px;
}

.cell {
display: table-cell;
}

.cell:nth-child(1) {
background-color: red;
width: 10%;
}

.cell:nth-child(2) {
background-color: green;
width: 50%;
}

.cell:nth-child(3) {
background-color: blue;
width: 20%;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eovYvO)

Answer (score 1):

The nth-child selector does not operate from the parent's perspective, rather the child element.

Think, instead of "This element's nth child", rather "If **I** am the nth child of a parent container"